# Calling an aura helper inside another helper not working after working for almost a month and the need to enable the controller class for profiles

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have an aura component with a lightning card and lightning record form inside the lightnign card. I have the init handler which calls the doinit controller which calls the helper:

```
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.checkToDisplayComponentClient(component);
        helper.getAllProductFieldsClient(component);
    }

getAllProductFieldsClient : function(component) {
        this.getProductSpecificFieldsClient(component);
    }
```

Initially in `getProductSpecificFieldsClient`  I was calling `getProductCommonFieldsClient`:

```
getProductSpecificFieldsClient : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getProductSpecificFields");
        action.setParams({oppId : component.get("v.recordId")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.productFields", response.getReturnValue());
                this.getProductCommonFieldsClient(component);
            } else if(state === "ERROR") {
                component.set("v.productFields", "");
                component.set("v.commonProductFields", "");
            }
        });
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

It was working for a month until now. Now, when I open an opportunity it was lightning cards under which common fields and specific fields should be displayed doesn't show anything.
If I move `getProductCommonFieldsClient` out of `getProductSpecificFieldsClient` and place it in `getAllProductFieldsClient` it works (see below).

```
getAllProductFieldsClient : function(component) {
        this.getProductCommonFieldsClient(component);
        this.getProductSpecificFieldsClient(component);
}
```

1. Why I do not understand.

If I modify `getProductSpecificFieldsClient` including the lines **var errors = response.getError(); console.log('state: products specific ' + errors[0].message);**, like below:

```
getProductSpecificFieldsClient : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getProductSpecificFields");
        action.setParams({oppId : component.get("v.recordId")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state products specific ' + state);
            var errors = response.getError();
            console.log('state: products specific errors ' + errors[0].message);
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log('state: products specific ' + response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.productFields", response.getReturnValue());
            } else if(state === "ERROR") {
                component.set("v.productFields", "");
                component.set("v.commonProductFields", "");
            }
        });
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

I am unable to display the specific fields for some reason.

2. I would expect a null pointer exception on console log because `var errors` are empty, but I am new to JS, so I am guessing thats just how JS works?
3. I had to `Enable Profile Access for Apex Class` for various profiles the controller class of this component, otherwise I was getting `You do not have access to the Apex class named...`, which is strange because I never did it before and it was working fine until now. Why now this error is occuring?

Comment: Point 3 is because of a critical update activated by Salesforce. Moving forward you will need to provide access of classes to profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a very powerful and tricky thing to master in JS.
In your code `this` holds the context which calls different methods in the aura component framework.

Using `this` in different loops changes the context values which it stores. So , while calling another helper method outside of a loop or callback function may or may not work at all times.

To overcome this challenge, a simple way is to store the value of `this` in another variable and use that new variable to call other helper methods. Something like this

```
let self= this; // should be first line inside a helper method
// some business logic
// some loop
self.getProductCommonFieldsClient(component);
```

On point 3 this is a critical update which was recently enforced by salesforce to enable more security on AuraEnabled Apex methods. You can read details [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_authenticated_users.htm)